# Best way to plot square grid of coordinates, each assigned a colour

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I am looking for the best way to plot data in the following format. I have 960 x 960 points equally divided over the range -2.2 and 2.2 in the x-axis and -2 and 2 in the y-axis. Based on some mathematics, each point is then assigned one of three colours.

The data is formatted as a 921600 long (960*960=921600) list with each element containing the 3 element list - `[x_value, y_value, colour]`, where colour is either 'r', 'b' or 'g'. The method I have used is just a scatter plot in matplotlib which gives an image similar to the following:

[image: matplotlib plotting of pixel-like coordinate data]

The code used for this is roughly:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
plt.ylabel("Velocity (x_dot OR y)")
plt.xlabel("Position (x)")
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, color = colour, marker = 's', s=0.5)
```

Although speed for plotting these images doesn't matter, I imagine that there is a neater way of doing this. I used this figure as an example as its file size is within the limit for stackoverflow images, however, when the image has a lot of mixed colours, the smoothed edges of the 's' square-like marker start to show and the image file size is very large.

I really only need one square/pixel for each coordinate and the labels are less important. Can anyone suggest a better way to plot this data? Thanks

Comment: You need to reshape the data and place them into one channel of an RGB image. If interested in answers with code, please provide a [mcve] (runnable code with ~10x10 pixels instead of a wordy description of the matter)

Comment: Is there a library you can recommend to do this with? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: numpy and matplotlib